# Is Fisher information well-defined here?

Tags: statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation, fisher-information

I am given a pdf $f_{\mu ,\sigma ^2}=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi \sigma ^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma ^2}\left(lnx-\mu \right)^2} $ and I need to find maximum likelihood estimators of both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ with corresponding Fisher information. My approach is to find log-likelihood function $l$ of each and take two derivatives. $\frac{dll}{d\mu} = 0$ gives me $\mu =ln \prod x_i $ and $\frac{d^2ll}{d^2\mu}$ gives the Fisher information. Can anyone tell me if I am moving to the right direction?

Comment: Yes it is well-defined. Just follow the definition; note that Fisher information of $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is a matrix.

Comment: So, I find both second partial derivative and write in the form \begin{bmatrix}
0 & I(\mu) \\
I(\sigma^2) & 0 
\end{bmatrix}?

Comment: $I(\mu)$ seems to be $\frac{n}{\sigma^2}. However, for $I(\sigma^2)$ there is not as beautiful, as it irreducible sum :(

Comment: When $\mu$ is constant, information of $\sigma^2$ based on a simple is $n/(2\sigma^4)$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3237921/321264). It should be a diagonal matrix BTW.

Comment: $ \frac{d{ll(\mu)}}{d\mu} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\ln{x_i}-\mu}{\sigma^2} $, $I = - \frac{d{ll(\sigma^2)}}{d\sigma^2} = \frac{n}{\sigma^2}?$ Am I doing something wrong? Note that the pdf in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3237921/321264 is slightly different, so the answer has to be also different...

Comment: I took the pdf into consideration in the last comment. I don't understand what you are writing, but there ought to be an expectation somewhere. What is your definition of Fisher information?

Comment: As I wrote in the question above, I assume that $I(\mu_{ml}) = -\frac{d^2ll}{d^2\mu}$, that is the second partial derivative with respect to $\mu$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: note that the given distribution is a known law: a [lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)

Then the MLE estimations can be obtained immediately and without any calculation, deriving them form the gaussian model.